# Issues mapping multiple Axis RTSP streams using FFMPEG

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

I have an application built in C# that leverages FFMPEG to map 3 h264 RTSP streams from Axis cameras along with a gdigrab screen recording and saves everything to a file using this command:

```
 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.200/axis-media/media.amp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.2.200/axis-media/media.amp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.3.200/axis-media/media.amp -r 30 -f gdigrab -framerate 1 -i title="MainWindow"  -c copy -map 0 -vcodec copy -map 1 -metadata title="6-26-2017-4-22-PM- TEST VIDEO" -vcodec copy -map 2 -vcodec copy -map 3 -vcodec h264 -preset ultrafast C:\Users\*USERNAME*\6-26-2017-4-22-PM-cam1comb.mkv
```

The issue that I'm having is that the Axis camera streams are out of sync with each other, with approximately a 3 second delay between the three streams.  When I test the FFMPEG command with all inputs changed to this stream `rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/_definst_/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4` as well as the screen grab however, everything works perfectly.

Comment: I have moved over to MJPEG for now, as the streams are in almost perfectly in sync with no additional tweaking on my part.  If anyone can help me with the RTSP issue however, it would be greatly appreciated, as MJPEG unfortunately does not have sound support.